# Golang unpack variadic arguments

Tags: go

How to unpack a variadic argument by `...` in golang:

```
func run(a, b string, list ...int) {
}

func call(list ...int) {
    run(x, y, list...) // use "list..." is not allowed 
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3}
    call(a...)
}
```

Why this is illegal? As i have known, the `list` argument is a slice which can be unpacked by `...`.

Comment: Your code seems to be working, [I tested it on Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yPYZsyW8DGBMay). May I know what error message did you get?

Answer (score 2):

> unpack variadic arguments

---

For your example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func run(a, b string, list ...int) {
    fmt.Println(list)
    for i, e := range list {
        fmt.Println(i, e)
    }
}

func call(list ...int) {
    fmt.Println(list)
    var x, y string
    run(x, y, list...) // use "list..." is allowed
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(a)
    call(a...)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NI0L-nVVUxm

Output:

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
0 1
1 2
2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

you didn't declare variables x and y. Create them or just use quotes. 
https://play.golang.org/p/gZnMALrM4Uh

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func run(a, b string, list ...int) {
fmt.Println(list)
}

func call(list ...int) {
    run("x", "y", list...) // ok
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3}
    call(a...)
}
```

Comment: This answer provides no explanation.

Comment: if you are able to read this code you can understand everything. Just compare snippet of question and this one ;)

Comment: This actually provides the best explanation of why OP's example didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Variadic arguments can only be expanded if the slice you're passing to the variadic function is *taking the place of* the variadic argument. You cannot combine individual arguments and an expanded slice in a single variadic argument for this reason. When you use expansion, the function receives the "expanded" slice itself as its variadic parameter - it's semantic sugar that can be confusing, because these calls are not equivalent:

```
foo := []string{"alpha","beta"}
bar(foo...) // bar receives the foo slice as its variadic parameter
bar(foo[0], foo[1]) // bar receives a new slice with these elements copied to it
```

You can find more details [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters), though the example they use makes some of the explanation unclear, because their example variadic function has multiple parameters. The section beginning "If the final argument is assignable" refers to the "final argument" not in a generic "final argument to a variadic function" sense, but in a specific "final argument to the function in the example" sense.